# Android Widget ListView goes empty on Background-Update

Tags: android, android-listview, widget

I'm using a ListView to display information in an Android Widget.

The information needs to be loaded from the Internet, which is loaded using an Async Task when the RemoveViewsFactory `onDataSetChanged` is called. When the Async Task finishes, the `onDataSetChanged` method is called again and the just received information is displayed.

While everything works fine initially, on the update initialized by Android ("updatePeriodMillis"), the ListView inside the Widget goes empty. I.e., neither the entries are displayed anymore nor the "No entries present" placeholder which is displayed when no entries are present.
The default update time of the Widget is set to one hour.

When I force a manual update (via a Button on the Widget), the entries show up again.

According to my Debug-Log Messages, the `onDataSetChanged` method is called before the entries disappear, forcing an update of the information. 
The `awm.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged` (`awm` is the `AppWidgetManager`) is called, but does not trigger the `public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position)` eventually (or this method returns `null`?) and also the `public int getCount()` is not called.

[Edit]
It seems like before the background poll finishes, the `getCount()` method is called and returns 0. However, after the `initData` method is called from the callback (i.e., after the new data is present) the `getCount()` is not called again. I could actually force an additional forced update without background loading then, but this would be more a hacky workaround than the actually correct way to do it.
[/Edit]

Since this is a rather rare event (minimum update time is 30 Minutes...), I find it very hard to debug it and hope for someone who has experienced a similar issue.

The full project is available here: [Github](https://github.com/MyTFG/mytfg-vplan-app)

Here is an excerpt of the Code:

```java
public class VplanWidgetDataProvider implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {
    // ...

    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() {
        plan = new Vplan(mContext, day);
        plan.loadFromCache();
        initData();
    }

    // ...

    private void initData() {
        Log.d("WIDGET", "INIT DATA: " + plan.getDay());
        nightmode = VplanWidget.useNightmode(mContext, widgetId);
        mCollection.clear();
        if (plan.isLoaded() && plan.upToDate()) {
            mCollection.clear();
            Log.d("WIDGET", "Data present");
            for (VplanEntry entry : plan.getEntries()) {
                mCollection.add(entry);
            }
            Log.d("WIDGET", "Entries: " + mCollection.size());
            Log.d("WIDGET", "Day: " + plan.getDayString());
            Log.d("WIDGET", "Date: " + plan.formatDate());
            Log.d("WIDGET", "NOTIFY");
            AppWidgetManager awm = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(mContext);
            awm.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(awm.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(mContext, VplanWidgetServiceToday.class)), R.id.widget_list_view);
            awm.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(awm.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(mContext, VplanWidgetServiceTomorrow.class)), R.id.widget_list_view);
        } else {
            Log.d("WIDGET", "Loading started");
            plan.load(new SuccessCallback() {
                @Override
                public void callback(boolean success) {
                    Log.d("WIDGET", "Loading finished: " + success);
                    if (success) {
                        onDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
        if (mCollection.size() <= position) {
            return null;
        }

        VplanEntry entry = mCollection.get(position);
        nightmode = VplanWidget.useNightmode(mContext, widgetId);

        int layout = nightmode ? R.layout.vplan_widget_entry_dark : R.layout.vplan_widget_entry;

        RemoteViews view = new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(), layout);
        view.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_plan_plan, entry.getPlan());
        view.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_plan_comment, entry.getComment());
        view.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_plan_substitution, entry.getSubstitution());
        view.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_plan_lesson, entry.getLesson());
        view.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_plan_cls, entry.getCls());

        if (entry.getComment().isEmpty()) {
            view.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_plan_comment, View.GONE);
        } else {
            view.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_plan_comment, View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if (entry.getSubstitution().isEmpty()) {
            view.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_plan_substitution, View.GONE);
        } else {
            view.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_plan_substitution, View.VISIBLE);
        }

        if (entry.getSubstitution().isEmpty() && entry.getComment().isEmpty()) {
            view.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_arrow, View.GONE);
        } else {
            view.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_arrow, View.VISIBLE);
        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And the `AppWidgetProvider`:

```java
public class VplanWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    // ...

    static void updateAppWidget(final Context context, final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                                final int appWidgetId, final boolean force) {

        Log.d("WIDGET", "UPDATE FOR WIDGET " + appWidgetId + " with Nightmode " + VplanWidget.useNightmode(context, appWidgetId));

        final CharSequence day = VplanWidgetConfigureActivity.loadDayPref(context, appWidgetId);
        CharSequence daystr;
        // Construct the RemoteViews object

        int layout = VplanWidget.useNightmode(context, appWidgetId) ? R.layout.vplan_widget_dark : R.layout.vplan_widget;

        final RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), layout);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_fab, getPendingSelfIntent(context, SYNC_CLICKED, appWidgetId));

        if (day.equals("today")) {
            daystr = context.getString(R.string.plan_today);
        } else {
            daystr = context.getString(R.string.plan_tomorrow);
        }

        final Vplan plan = new Vplan(context, day.toString());
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_title, daystr);

        MyTFGApi api = new MyTFGApi(context);

        if (!api.isLoggedIn()) {
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_plan_empty, context.getString(R.string.widget_login_required));
            views.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_plan_empty, View.VISIBLE);
            views.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_list_view, View.GONE);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
            return;
        }
        //views.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_fab, View.GONE);

        long updateInt = force ? 0 : plan_update;
        Log.d("WIDGET", "UPDATE FORCE: " + force);

        views.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_plan_empty, context.getString(R.string.plan_empty));

        views.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_title, context.getString(R.string.plan_loading));
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

        plan.load(new SuccessCallback() {
            @Override
            public void callback(boolean success) {
                //views.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_fab, View.VISIBLE);
                Log.d("WIDGET", "UPDATE COMPLETED: " + success);
                if (success) {
                    Date update = new Date();
                    update.setTime(plan.getTimestamp());
                    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM. HH:mm", Locale.GERMANY);
                    String diff = format.format(update);
                    views.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_changed, context.getString(R.string.widget_last_update) + " " + diff);

                    views.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_title, plan.formatDate());
                    if (plan.getEntries().size() == 0) {
                        views.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_plan_empty, View.VISIBLE);
                        views.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_list_view, View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        views.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_plan_empty, View.GONE);
                        views.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_list_view, View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    setRemoteAdapter(context, views, day.toString(), appWidgetId);
                    appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetId, R.id.widget_list_view);
                }
                // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
            }
        }, force, updateInt);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }


    private static void setRemoteAdapter(Context context, @NonNull final RemoteViews views, String day, int appWidgetId) {
        Intent intent;
        switch (day) {
            default:
            case "today":
                intent = new Intent(context, VplanWidgetServiceToday.class);
                break;
            case "tomorrow":
                intent = new Intent(context, VplanWidgetServiceTomorrow.class);
                break;
        }
        intent.putExtra("day", day);
        intent.setData(Uri.fromParts("content", String.valueOf(appWidgetId), null));
        intent.putExtra("random", randomNum);
        randomNum++;
        views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.widget_list_view, intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post project on github? it's pretty hard to help you without full sources :/

Comment: I edited my question and added the Link to the Github Repo.